# Rails 5: Send form via AJAX, modifying inputs first, and append a view to the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

*(This question has been written to focus only on what is relevant.)*

Within a page view I have a Rails form:

```
<%= form_for @model, url: {controller: 'foo', action: 'bar'} do |f| %>
  <!-- various inputs -->
  <%= f.button "Submit", type: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click the 'Submit' button, I would like to:

1. Modify some of the inputs before sending
2. Send the form via AJAX
3. Replace the form with the view corresponding to the controller action (/views/foo/bar.html.erb)

What's the cleanest way to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Enable form submission via ajax using `remote: true` option**

```
<%= form_for @model, url: {controller: 'foo', action: 'bar'}, remote: true do |f| %>
```

**2. Modify inputs before form submit**

```
$('form.model_name').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  //Modify inputs
});
```

**3. Replace the form with the view corresponding to the controller action (/views/foo/bar.html.erb)**

In the action where the form is handled:

```
def create
  ....
  .....
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**4. create a `.js.erb` template where the other templates for this controller are placed**

***create.js***

```
$('form.model_name').html("<%= j(render 'foo/bar.html.erb') %>")`
```

And that's it!

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to leave the controller alone, and use the (client-side) .coffee file to simply append foo/create.html.erb?  It seems like this should be so easy but I can't find an example anywhere.

Comment: You can't leave controller alone. That is the one which processes requests and prepares response. Yes, it is possible to avoid using `html.erb` by exposing APIs which returns JSON response and your client scripting jQeury/handlebar/React/Angular take care of rendering.

Comment: What I'm saying is that for a normal (non AJAX)  HTTP request you can leave the controller action blank and Rails will render the corresponding view to send back. I can't understand why, for an AJAX request, Rails wouldn't render the view (minus the layout) to send back by default (i.e., if there is no code in the controller action saying to do something else).

Comment: Rails follows Convention over Configuration and assumes smart defaults. If you don't mention `render` or `redirect`into the action. It tries to search template in relevant path with same name as actions. I would highly recommend to go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org